# Stopping all other animations using no selector in $.animate with step()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm animating objects using arrays in my selector which I am stuck using for a specific reason in another [SO post I made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53892540/preventing-jquery-from-using-scientific-notation-in-animate).

How am I able to stop other animations that have been started from arbitrary array values? E.g: `$({ x: 0 }).animate({`

For example:

```
$({ x: 0 }).animate({
      x: 500
  }, {
      easing: 'linear',
      duration: 15000,
      step: function(now, fx) {
          // $(this).stop();
          var current_styles = $(selector).attr('style'),
              current_styles = string = current_styles.split(" ");

          var x = parseFloat(current_styles[1].replace('px', '').replace(';', ''));

          if ('x' === fx.prop) {
              x = now;
          }

          $(selector).attr({ style: 'margin-left: ' + x + 'px;' });

      },
      complete: function() {
          //
      }
  });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row row_1"><button data-id="1">GO</button><div class="box" style="margin-left: 0;"></div></div>
<div class="row row_2"><button data-id="2">GO</button><div class="box" style="margin-left: 0;"></div></div>
<div class="row row_3"><button data-id="3">GO</button><div class="box" style="margin-left: 0;"></div></div>
<div class="row row_4"><button data-id="4">GO</button><div class="box" style="margin-left: 0;"></div></div>
<div class="row row_5"><button data-id="5">GO</button><div class="box" style="margin-left: 0;"></div></div>
<div class="row row_6"><button data-id="6">GO</button><div class="box" style="margin-left: 0;"></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
  background-color: green;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  width: 600px;
}
.box {
  background-color: red;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
button {
  float: left;
}
```

I want to stop all *other* animations when I start this one. However, I cannot use `$(selector).stop();` as it does not work.

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7vk9d2te/5/) & gif of issue:**

[image: https://jsfiddle.net/7vk9d2te/5/]
**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7vk9d2te/7/) of desired results (Using incorrect formatting for my purpose):**

[image]

You can stop an animation from within a `step()` using `$(this).stop();` but that only stops the one animation you are inside.

Basically, I need to be able to stop all *other* animations and then continue with the animation that was just started. The JS itself works exactly as intended, I just need to stop the old animations in their tracks as the new one starts.

It's not clear to me of an elegant nor easy way to do this when using:

```
$({ x: 0 }).animate({
```

Thank you for taking the time to consider my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the previous started animation in a variable so you can access it (to retrieve the current value and to stop it):

```
var prevAnimation;

function runAnimation(selector) {

  var start = 0;
  if (prevAnimation) {
    start = prevAnimation.get(0).x;
    prevAnimation.stop();
  }

  prevAnimation = $({ x: start }).animate({
      x: 500
  }, {
      easing: 'linear',
      // And so on
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7vk9d2te/9/

-- Update --

If your animation is just about the margin-left, you could really simplify your code by removing the step function and letting jQuery do the magic with

```
function runAnimation(selector) {

  var start = 0;
  if (prevAnimation) {
    start = parseFloat(prevAnimation.css('margin-left'));
    prevAnimation.stop();
  }

  prevAnimation = $(selector)
      .css('margin-left', start + 'px')
      .animate({ 'margin-left': 500 }, {
         easing: 'linear',
         duration: 15000,
      });
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7vk9d2te/10/

Comment: Thank you!!! This works perfectly. By the end I was trying to push the animation to an array using IDs and then check on lower ids and end them... bleh - still didn't work! This is very elegant - appreciate it.